# Can Masque Use his Power to Suffocate Someone?

Tags: marvel, x-men

While looking at different Wikipedia articles on different X-Men characters, I found a character named Masque, who can reshape a person's skin any way he wishes. I was just curious: Could he do this and reshape their face so the holes to their nose and mouth were blocked?

Comment: Very probably. If he can use his powers to remove a mouth and stop them speaking... http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-DzMjqGBgDlU/UAv3kgtCs7I/AAAAAAAABn4/uZ1XpX1polg/s1600/X-MEN191_04a-2.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, he can.  Masque's powers allow for fairly extensive reconfigurations.  In addition to being able to alter hair and skin color, he can also remove orifices (and presumably add new ones).

Issue #179 contains both of these, used on Kitty Pryde:

This panel showcases his abilities, including removing all features from her face:
[image]

And in this panel, as well as making her ugly, Masque blocks her airway, and Callisto makes it explicit that that's what's happening.
[image]

In other encounters with the X-Men, Masque has also closed up Banshee's mouth so he couldn't speak and created tentacle arms for Callisto.

Comment: Thanks. Pretty cool how this dude's powers work, since Toad's slime and Magneto's metal attacks can be removed by force, while if this guy refuses to change back, say Kitty above, for example, she would pretty much be screwed.

Comment: @Xfan25 there's always tracheotomies.

Comment: @fectin-Still wouldn't help her deformed face.